# Python: how to split 2d array into many small

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I want to split my 10x10 array into small 2x2 arrays. I was trying to use *itertools.product()* but nothing worked correctly. Also, I am not going to use numpy. Here is the code:

```
ar = [[1,2,3,4],
      [5,6,7,8,],
      [9,10,11,12],
      [13,14,15,16]]
l=[]
for i in ar:
    for j in i:
l+=j
ans = []
for i in range(0,len(l) + 1, 2):
    ans.append(l[i:i+2])
    ans.append(l[i+4:i+6])
```

What I expect is: `[[1,5,2,6],[3,7,4,8],[9,13,10,14],[11,15,12,16]]`

What I get:`[[1, 2], [5, 6], [3, 4], [7, 8], [5, 6], [9, 10], [7, 8], [11, 12], [9, 10], [13, 14], [11, 12], [15, 16], [13, 14], [], [15, 16], [], [], []]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
for i, j in itertools.product(range(0,nrows,h), range(0,ncols,w))
```

to iterate over the starting indices for each small array, and use

```
for dj, di in itertools.product(range(w), range(h))
```

to iterate over the elements in the small array. For example,

```
import itertools as IT
ar = [[1,2,3,4],
      [5,6,7,8,],
      [9,10,11,12],
      [13,14,15,16]]

nrows, ncols = len(ar), len(ar[0])
h, w = 2, 2

print([[ar[i+di][j+dj] for dj, di in IT.product(range(w), range(h))]
       for i, j in IT.product(range(0,nrows,h), range(0,ncols,w))])
```

prints

```
[[1, 5, 2, 6], [3, 7, 4, 8], [9, 13, 10, 14], [11, 15, 12, 16]]
```

---

If you wish to replace the [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with for-loops, the equivalent would be

```
ans = []
for i, j in IT.product(range(0,nrows,h), range(0,ncols,w)):
    small_array = []
    for dj, di in IT.product(range(w), range(h)):
        small_array.append(ar[i+di][j+dj])
    ans.append(small_array)
print(ans)
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if I want to get little squares with step = 1?
If ar = [[1,2,3,4],
           [5,6,7,8,],
           [9,10,11,12],
           [13,14,15,16]];  
Then the answer should be : [[1, 5, 2, 6], [2, 6, 3, 7], [3, 7, 4, 8], [9, 13, 10, 14], [10, 14, 11, 15], [11, 15, 12, 16]]

Comment: Then you would want to change `for i, j in IT.product(range(0,nrows,h), range(0,ncols,w))` to `for i, j in IT.product(range(0,nrows,h), range(3))`.